# SteadyState alternatives for Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, kiosk, deep-freeze, steadystate

On their Vista PCs, my library uses Windows SteadyState to discard changes patrons make to system.  Recently, one of those machines had to be re-imaged with stock version of Vista that came with the machine.  Steadystate is no longer available from Microsoft.  I saw [this list of alternatives](http://www.instantfundas.com/2010/09/5-alternatives-to-windows-steadystate.html), but I am willing to consider other alternatives, such as [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/).

**Which of these alternatives provides the closest experience to Windows SteadyState, in terms of administrative functionality and end-user experience?**

Comment: Oops, looks like my edit inadvertently deleted some of the links you posted. Feel free to edit back in your links to lists of possible products. However, I'm pretty sure that anyone aiming to answer this question is already going to have a piece of software in mind, and will not need these lists to answer the question. If someone has already used a piece of software for Vista/7 that is extremely similar in functionality to SteadyState, I am sure that they will tell us.

Comment: Note that SteadyState does work fine if you can still find the installer...

Comment: I can't find it on microsoft.com.  I see a lot of 3rd party sites hosting the installer but I don't trust them.

Comment: Why don't you simply duplicate one of the other systems hdd?  I assume they are all similar, and if they are not, you can use programs like Acronis that can migrate an existing system to a new system and log into SteadyState and allow the new configurations to stick.

Comment: @Sajee - I am pretty sure you can trust CNET - http://download.cnet.com/Windows-SteadyState/3000-18512_4-11127965.html

Comment: I thought so too but...: http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2130382/cnet-accused-bundling-malware-downloads